# Making a tree from two column csv file in java

Tags: java, lookup

I want to have ids and count of all the child of a node using two-column CSV file in which one column is parent id and one is child id.

For e.g

```
Child Id   Parent Id
C1         C2
C3         C1
C4         C3
```

I want result like this:

```
C2  C1, C3, C4 3
```

Comment: So, what's stopping you from doing that?

Comment: I  don't have idea how to do this in java

Comment: and do you have an idea how to do this in any other language?

Comment: If you want to get the number of child nodes of a particular node, you have to count the number of lines where Parent Id column's value equals your node (assuming you do not have duplicates).

Comment: parent ids can also be found in child ids as it also has some parent as its like tree structure. See in e.g C1 is in parent id and also in child id.

Comment: I have written the code in r but the file is too large so it is taking time to execute there @smoczyna

Comment: Read carefully what I've just written: "count the number of lines where Parent Id column's value equals your node ". It means you should ignore Child Id column and count only occurrences in Parent Id

Comment: read this first, it will give you an idea how to start suh things in java: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/95084/parsing-a-text-file-of-node-data-into-nodes-and-edges

Comment: If you also want to count child nodes of a found child node, use recursion then.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear. Do you have some code or visual representation of it? 
If I correctly understand, You can make not tree, but just Map, where Key is ParentId and value is Integer of your Child, or Object
It is possible to look like

```
class Child {
List<String> ids;
int count;

    public Child(String id) {
        count=1;
        if (ids.size() < 1) {
            ids = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        ids.add(id);
    }

        public Child setChild(String id) {
        if (ids.size() < 1) {
            ids = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        ids.add(id);
        count++;
        return this;
    }

class Main{

//your logic
Map<String, Child> map = new HashMap<>();
    if (!map.containsKey(parent)){
        map.put(parent,new Child(id));
    }else
    map.computeIfPresent(parent, (key, value) -> value.setChild(id));
}
```

**P.S**

If you need only count your child, so do that

```
 String parent = "";
 Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

if (!map.containsKey(parent)) {
      map.put(parent, 1);
} else {
      map.computeIfPresent(parent, (key, value) -> new Integer(value.intValue()+1));
        }
```

Here pseudo-parent is use, but you should insert your own parent.

Comment: if you need only child`s count instead full id and count, it`s easier, cause you don't need any object, only counter which you will increase if parent already in map

Comment: how to get only count without ids will you please tell me in code

Comment: look at my p.s .  Your own parrent should be something like `String [] line; String parent = line[i]` where `i` is each line of your file. Of course you should also delimit parent and child, but it is not hard and you can find it in web